# jQuery using the .delay() method in an .each() loop

Tags: jquery

With the following code I want the li elements to fade in one by one, but the all fade in together:

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Can anyone explain why they do not fade in one by one?

Comment: Well, you're assigning the same 1 second delay to each.

Comment: For the same reason doing a setTimeout in a loop with all the same delay happen all at the same time.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/ "Using the standard effects queue, we can, for example, set an 800-millisecond delay between the .slideUp() and .fadeIn() of <div id="foo">:
`$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );`

Only for anaimation, not a sleep to js

Comment: and, each li gets it's own queue in this case.

Comment: @Jason210 did you want "1s delay, 1s fade, 1s delay, 1s fade, ...", or just "fade, fade, fade..." with 1s between each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.delay` call doesn't stop the loop from carrying on immediately, so all of the delays and animations will start (pretty much) at once.

The most trivial solution is to stagger the delay by the current index number:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

A better solution would use a pseudo-recursive loop and the "completion callback" of the animation to trigger the next iteration:

```
var els = $('li').get();
(function loop() {
    if (els.length) {
        var el = els.shift();
        $(el).fadeIn(1000, loop);
    }
})();
```

This method is generally preferable because it ensures that the next fade-in cannot possibly start until the previous has finished, and also avoids creating multiple parallel delay / fade queues (one per element) since the 2nd animation isn't queued until the first has finished.

Comment: `delay(1000)` is not needed any more in your loop version, I think

Comment: @fengd good point, but does depend on the OP's intent.  The original code (if it had worked synchronously) would have done delay, fade, delay, fade...

Comment: Yes, it does help to see it done another way. Thank you.

Comment: I did it like this: $(this).delay(1000 * index).fadeIn(1000);

Comment: @Jason210 right, so that means there's _no initial delay_, and that the other delays (in theory) just arrange for the next fade to start immediately after the next.  I'll update accordingly.

Comment: the `completion callback` part has done the delay part. @Alnitak

Comment: @fengd indeed, but (per above) it was unclear whether the OP expect _both_ the delay and fade to be sync, or whether he already knew that the fade would be async.   On the basis of his comments I've now removed the `.delay()` from the pseudo-recursive version.

Comment: @Alnitak - yes, that's what I had in mind from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because you basically telling each `li` to wait 1 sec and to fade in. So that's what they do :)

**Right now, your code is similar to:**

```
$('li').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

Try something like that :

```
var delay = 0;
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(1000);
    delay += 1000;
});
```

Or, as **Alnitak** suggest, **a cleaner way is to use the current index provided by `$.each()`** :

```
$('li').each(function (index) {
    // index will return the loop index starting to 0
    $(this).delay(index*1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: you do know that `.each` provides the current iteration count?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to make something more readable to @Jason210

Comment: NB: the delay starts at 1000, not 0

Comment: Not sure about that, usually, the first animation starts on page load (it would make no sense to wait 1 second for the first anim).

Comment: perhaps not, but that's what the OP's code would do if it weren't async

Comment: And same thing to the downvoter: why serial downvote?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, the OP's doesn't know how to achieve that :) Usually, that's what customers ask for.

Comment: Now it's all very clear. I was trying it out, and would no doubt have modified the code to fade in on page load. But I was stumped when it first didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

cause `each` is not delayed. Every delay is applied almost at the same time.

you may want to try use the `complete` part do `fadeIn` the next element

```
.fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )
```

[jQuery api doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a misunderstanding of `jQuery.each`. It doesn't mean do it for one, then wait for that to finish before moving on, for that you'd need to use a promise.

Instead, try changing your delay to a multiple of the index of each LI in the array, e.g.:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
  $(this).delay((index + 1) * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Since array indices always start from 0, and 0 * 1000 = 0, I've added 1 to the index before multiplying by 1000 to ensure the first one happens after 1 second, the second after 2 seconds and so on.

If you don't want a 1s delay to the first `li` fading in, then it's simply:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
  $(this).delay(index * 1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: no need for promises here - animations provide a "completion callback"

Comment: @Alnitak I know they're not needed in this instance, I was highlighting that to achieve that sort of behaviour in a loop (in general terms) would require the use of promises. Teach a man to fish and all that ;-)

Comment: You can't write (traditional) loops using promises.